# After installing Deno, linting issues arise in VSCode Nodejs project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, deno

[image: Linting Errors]

I have installed Deno recently, I am aware of all the default settings have been changed to TypeScript. Although, whenever I am working on a plain javascript nodejs project, the javascript lint is not working properly ever since.

The IntelliSense is also not working for sure. I have Nodejs version 12 installed.

[image]

Comment: disable the deno extension for the workspace (when working with node.js project)

Comment: I did, It didnt work though

Comment: How did you install deno and what os are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, I installed through powershell commands mentioned on their official docs.

Answer (score 1):

install 'denoland' extension and add this config.

on the root of your project: create a hidden folder and inside settings.json :

.vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "deno.enable": true,
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "denoland.vscode-deno"
    },
    "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "denoland.vscode-deno"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to disable deno extension in your VSCode when working with Node.js projects. After disabling try to close VSCode and open it again.